# What can i do add title to 'large' image?

Tags: images, post-thumbnails, title

```
 <?php 
 if ( has_post_thumbnail()) {
   $large_image_url = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id(), 'large');
   echo '<a href="' . $large_image_url[0] . '" >';
   the_post_thumbnail('medium');
   echo '</a>';
 }
 ?>
```

This code adds a big image to the thumbnail image. What can I do add title to 'large' image?

Comment: I add this code  title="' . the_title_attribute('echo=0') . '"  but it is add title page, i need title thumbnail image.

Comment: What 'title' are you trying to add?  The image's title?

Comment: Yes it is, Pat, i try add title of image...

Answer (score 2):

Check the Codex. [`the_post_thumbnail`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/the_post_thumbnail) accepts two parameters, the second of which is `$attr`-- "attributes".

```
the_post_thumbnail('full',array('title'=>'yay! a title!'));
```

The Codex entry for [`the_post_thumbnail`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/the_post_thumbnail) is not clear on what is and is not allowed as an "attribute" but it appears to depend on [`wp_get_attachment_image`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_get_attachment_image) and by filters applied by that function. `title` does work though. I checked.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you mean `title` attribute or title as in caption. The code below would echo the image title as a caption.

EDIT - up-voted @s_ha_dum's answer as it looks like you were looking for the title attribute.

EDIT - `wp_get_attachment_image_src' returns an array with the image URL in the first position.

```
<?php 
if ( has_post_thumbnail()) {
   $your_thumb_id = get_post_thumbnail_id();
   $args = array(
     'post_type' => 'attachment',
     'numberposts' => 1,
     'post_status' => null,
     'p' => $your_thumb_id
   );

   $attachments = get_posts( $args );
   if ( $attachments ) {
      foreach ( $attachments as $attachment ) {
         $large_src = wp_get_attachment_image_src( $attachment->ID, 'large' );
         echo '<a href="' . $large_src[0] . '">';
         echo wp_get_attachment_image($attachment->ID,'medium');
         echo '</a>';
         echo '<p>';
         echo apply_filters( 'the_title', $attachment->post_title );
         echo '</p>';
      }
   }
} ?>
```

Comment: Missing a `;` on about line 3.

Comment: This code adds a link to the thumbnail - "www.mydomen/Array"  ?Now the thumbnail does not appear in the lightbox, just running this link - "www.mydomen/Array"...

Comment: Don't know why `wp_get_image_src` returns an array, but I've edited the code to reflect that. I should be returning the source correctly now.